# Tapestry5 : Non select the radio button

Tags: tapestry

I am having two radio buttons on my first.tml pag, when the page renders the first button comes out to be selected bydefault. I don't it this way , my requirement is radio button to be selected by user not as default value.

Answer (score 2):

Whether the radio button is selected or not depends on the `value` binding of its `RadioGroup`:

```
<t:radiogroup t:value="myProperty">
    <t:radio t:value="myRadioButtonValue"/>
</t:radiogroup>
```

When the radio group's value (`myProperty`) equals the value specified for the button (`myRadioButtonValue`), then the radio button is rendered as selected, otherwise as deselected, just like you'd expect.

If you want no selection as the default, you need to set the value in your backing bean (`myProperty`) to null.